# multicore::sapply?

Tags: r, multicore

Is there anything like `sapply` in the `multicore` library? Or do I have to `unlist(mclapply(..))` in order to achieve this?

If it does not exist: what would the reasoning be?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a stupid question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code of `sapply` (and its helper function `simplify2array`) you will see that `unlist(obj)` is exactly what will be done in the case where obj is a list of items all of `length==1`. `sapply` is a lot more complex than just unlisting lists, however. What is still very unclear is what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 5):

In the library `parallel`, you have `mcmapply` which, like `mapply` in `base`, takes a `SIMPLIFY` argument. It is `TRUE` by default. Here is an example use:

```
library(parallel)
mcmapply(sqrt,split(1:8,1:8))
#        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
# 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068 2.449490 2.645751 2.828427
```

Compare this to the use of `mclapply`.

```
mclapply(split(1:8,1:8),sqrt)
# $`1`
# [1] 1
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 1.414214
# ...
```

Comment: In some ways, however, I agree that it is weird that there is no `mcsapply`. I always thought it was weird that you couldn't pass a `SIMPLIFY` argument to `lapply`, but I suspect that is the reason why you can't pass a `SIMPLIFY` argument to `mclapply`.

Comment: Isn't it just that case that mclapply is acting on lists and therefore returns lists by default in the same way sapply acts on vectors and simplify is true by default?

Comment: @rpierce Actually `sapply` acts on lists as well (and `lapply` works on vectors too). The only difference between `sapply` and `lapply` is the structure of the returned value. `lapply` will *always* return a list, while `sapply` may return a vector or a list. The names of the returned value are also different. I believe that it would make a lot of sense to create an `mcsapply` that had the same behaviour as `sapply`.

Comment: I concur. I'm building it into my next release of mcparallelDo.

Answer (score 1):

just like IRTFM mentionned, looking at source code of sapply is the answer. But since I was still a bit confused after reading his answer, maybe it's me, so if you were too then hopefully following precision will make it clearer :
code of sapply :

```
sapply<-function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
{
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  answer <- lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
  if (USE.NAMES && is.character(X) && is.null(names(answer))) 
    names(answer) <- X
  if (!isFALSE(simplify) && length(answer)) 
    simplify2array(answer, higher = (simplify == "array"))
  else answer
}
```

so a homemade implementation of mcsapply would be :

```
mcsapply<-function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE, mc.preschedule = TRUE,
 mc.set.seed = TRUE, mc.silent = FALSE, mc.cores = getOption("mc.cores", 2L), 
  mc.cleanup = TRUE, mc.allow.recursive = TRUE, affinity.list = NULL )
{
  answer <- mclapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...,mc.preschedule = mc.preschedule, 
mc.set.seed = mc.set.seed, mc.silent = mc.silent, mc.cores = mc.cores, 
  mc.cleanup = mc.cleanup, mc.allow.recursive = mc.allow.recursive, affinity.list = affinity.list)
  if (USE.NAMES && is.character(X) && is.null(names(answer))) 
    names(answer) <- X
  if (!isFALSE(simplify) && length(answer)) 
    simplify2array(answer, higher = (simplify == "array"))
  else answer
}
```

I am using similar implementation and it works just fine.