# Parallelizing the R code using mclapply does not generate the correct results

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data-manipulation, sapply, mclapply

I have a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) `df` and need to apply a function that gives a score to each columns (`calc.fitness`):

```
    df
  #         ch1     ch2   ch3    ch4   ch5    ch6   ch7   ch8
  # g1       5      2      7     10     7     10    10    6
  # g2       1      4      5      4     1     2     5     4
  # g3      16      14     7      4     2     2     8     7
  # g4       7      5      5      3     2     5     1     6
  # g5       7      2      1      3     7     2     4     1
  # g6       4      7      11     4     9     3     9     14
  # g7      12      8      6      7     5     9     7     4
  # g8       4      2      3      2     2     4     1     1
  # g9       1      2      1      1     2     1     2     1
```

using [sapply](/questions/tagged/sapply), I will get the following results which is the correct one but very time consuming as size of `df` increases:

```
sapply(as.list(df), calc.fitness,filterTable=my.df)
#     ch1          ch2            ch3            ch4            ch5            ch6            ch7             ch8 
# 8.481359e-02  6.419552e-01   5.847587e-02   6.713477e-02   1.552056e-01   1.305787e+34   2.805074e-01    2.039931e+00
```

I used [Tag:mclapply` to make it faster as follows:

```
numCores <- detectCores()
result <- unlist(mclapply(1:8, function(x) {
  return(calc.fitness(df[,x], filterTable=my.df))}, mc.preschedule = TRUE, mc.cores = numCores))

# result
# [1] 8.481359e-02 8.481359e-02 8.481359e-02 8.481359e-02 1.305787e+34 1.305787e+34 1.305787e+34 1.305787e+34
```

But as results show, `mclapply` does not work correctly and I do not know what is the problem and how to fix. I really appreciate any help!

PS: `calc.fitness` is a long method, I tried to make it shorter here:

```
calc.fitness <- function(df.val, filterTable = my.df) {
  input.path <- "/home/Nikki/Desktop/v2017.0/exec/Input_2017.txt"
  filterTable$xe <-  df.val[1]
  filterTable$xth <- df.val[2]
  filterTable$xfi <- df.val[3]
  filterTable$xfw <- df.val[4]
  filterTable$xfm <- df.val[5]
  filterTable$xls <- df.val[6]
  filterTable$xhls <- df.val[7]
  filterTable$xvt <- df.val[8]
  filterTable$xvd <- df.val[9]
  write.fwf(filterTable,append = TRUE,file = paste("Input_2017", ".txt", sep = ""),width = 25, rownames = F,colnames = F,quote = F)
  command <- "wine  /home/Nikki/Desktop/v2017.0/exec/2017File.exe"
  system(command)
  output.file <-read.table("/home/Nikki/Desktop/v2017.0/exec/Output_2017.txt",header = TRUE,fill = TRUE)
  output.pgt <- as.numeric(levels(output.file$pgt))[output.file$pgt]
  calc.sol <- output.pgt[!is.na(output.pgt)]
  opt.sol <- filterTable$PressureDropGL
  n <- length(calc.sol)
  subtract.val <- calc.sol - opt.sol
  denominator <- opt.sol
  sq.output <-  (subtract.val / denominator) ^ 2
  fitness.val <- sum(sq.output) / n
  return(fitness.val)
}# end of function
```

my.df:

[image]

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Nikki, it will be easier to help if you provide the code for the function `calc.fitness` or the package it comes from.

Comment: Hi Ian, calc.fitness is a long function which I wrote, I tried to make it shorter and understandable! I edited the post and you can see the function!
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: After seeing your function, you are appending data generated in it to one file. That may work fine if done sequentially, but when you do that in a parallel processes you are bound to run into trouble. See my edited comment.

Answer (score 1):

`sapply` simplifies to a matrix, while unlisting your list of columns returns the vectors of each column, one after the other. Consider using the `cumsum` function as illustration:

```r
df <-
    structure(
        list(
            ch1 = c(5L, 1L, 16L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 1L),
            ch2 = c(2L, 4L, 14L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 2L),
            ch3 = c(7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 1L),
            ch4 = c(10L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 1L),
            ch5 = c(7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 2L),
            ch6 = c(10L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 1L),
            ch7 = c(10L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 2L),
            ch8 = c(6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 1L)
        ),
        class = "data.frame",
        row.names = c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5", "g6", "g7", "g8", "g9")
    )

sapply(as.list(df), cumsum)
#>       ch1 ch2 ch3 ch4 ch5 ch6 ch7 ch8
#>  [1,]   5   2   7  10   7  10  10   6
#>  [2,]   6   6  12  14   8  12  15  10
#>  [3,]  22  20  19  18  10  14  23  17
#>  [4,]  29  25  24  21  12  19  24  23
#>  [5,]  36  27  25  24  19  21  28  24
#>  [6,]  40  34  36  28  28  24  37  38
#>  [7,]  52  42  42  35  33  33  44  42
#>  [8,]  56  44  45  37  35  37  45  43
#>  [9,]  57  46  46  38  37  38  47  44

unlist(parallel::mclapply(1:8, function(x) {
    return(cumsum(df[,x]))}, mc.preschedule = TRUE, mc.cores = 4L))
#>  [1]  5  6 22 29 36 40 52 56 57  2  6 20 25 27 34 42 44 46  7 12 19 24 25 36 42
#> [26] 45 46 10 14 18 21 24 28 35 37 38  7  8 10 12 19 28 33 35 37 10 12 14 19 21
#> [51] 24 33 37 38 10 15 23 24 28 37 44 45 47  6 10 17 23 24 38 42 43 44

do.call(cbind, parallel::mclapply(1:8, function(x) {
    return(cumsum(df[,x]))}, mc.preschedule = TRUE, mc.cores = 4L))
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#>  [1,]    5    2    7   10    7   10   10    6
#>  [2,]    6    6   12   14    8   12   15   10
#>  [3,]   22   20   19   18   10   14   23   17
#>  [4,]   29   25   24   21   12   19   24   23
#>  [5,]   36   27   25   24   19   21   28   24
#>  [6,]   40   34   36   28   28   24   37   38
#>  [7,]   52   42   42   35   33   33   44   42
#>  [8,]   56   44   45   37   35   37   45   43
#>  [9,]   57   4618   46   38   37   38   47   44
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Edit:** 
After seeing your function, you are appending data generated in it to one file. That may work fine if done sequentially, but when you do that in a parallel processes you are bound to run into trouble. Spawning multiple wine processes in parallel by itself may also not be the most efficient procedure to begin with, even if it yielded the correct results (profiling your (linear) code with the `profvis` package would show you the bottleneck). Is there any alternative to the `2017File.exe` to calculate the `fitness.val`?

If your plan was truly to sequentially append results from columns, then to properly initiate the parallel generation of results with your exe file, you may have to save unique instances of the sequentially growing file (your write.fwf command) and then pass those in parallel to the exe command, generating unique output.txt files for each sequential step, and then load the results from that in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

If it works with sapply but not with mclapply, it is surely because sapply and lapply slightly differ, and what you would like to use is something like mcsapply instead of mclapply.

If it is the case, you will find an implementation of mcsapply in following duplicate answer, that make use extensive use of in my code :
[multicore::sapply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043633/multicoresapply/67090929#67090929)

I guess this question is a duplicate of this one by the way